# Why does Pandas Series slicing behave differently when slicing using index numbers versus index values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

Came across this problem and was curious why the values for slicing using the index numbers is exclusive at the end but using the index values was inclusive. Here's a short reproducible example. I apologize if I'm using improper terminology.

```
# start with a pandas series
series = pd.Series(np.arange(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

# slicing using index values
series['b':'e']

## returns
| b| 1|
| c| 2|
| d| 3|
| e| 4|

# slicing using index numbers
series[1:4]

## returns
| b| 1|
| c| 2|
| d| 3|
```

Why wouldn't they return the same output? Isn't `'b':'e'` the same as indices `1:4` in the series?

Comment: Numeric indices are treated as they are in other Python contexts.  String indices include the last entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this has been answered before hence a community wiki.

According to the [Slicing with Labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-slicing-with-labels) documentation:

> When using .loc with slices, if both the start and the stop labels are present in the index, then elements located between the two (including them) are returned

This happens when you do:

```
series['b':'e']
```

Because we are slicing by labels and not positions. Hence the labels are inclusive.

However when you slice by position using `iloc` for example, it behaves a bit differently. It takes into account the first position and excludes the last, pretty much like how python indexing works

Hence `series[1:4]` excludes the position 4 from the slice.
Read more on [slicing by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-integer)

One can also replicate this when the labels are same as positions:

```
pd.Series(np.arange(5)).loc[1:4]
```

this returns index 1,2,3,4 whereas the below:

```
pd.Series(np.arange(5))[1:4]
```

Excludes the index==4.